# How to apply function to multiple columns based on value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

Let's say I have a dataframe as follow:

| unit | altitude_low | altitude_high |
| --- | --- | --- |
| meter | 456 | 25435 |
| meter | 254 | 35223 |
| feet | 34 | 3256 |
| feet | 46 | 234 |
| meter | 456 | 45776 |

How do I convert the value of both altitude columns to meter if the **unit column** is feet?
I tried:

```
def convert_to_m(row):  
    if row['unit'] == "feet":
        row['altitude_low ']= row['altitude_low ']/3.281
        row['altitude_high']= row['altitude_high']/3.281 
    else:
        pass 

df= df.apply(lambda row: convert_to_m(row), axis= "columns")
```

but this failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df['unit'].eq('feet'), ['altitude_low','altitude_high']] /= 3.281
```

Output:

```
    unit  altitude_low  altitude_high
0  meter    456.000000   25435.000000
1  meter    254.000000   35223.000000
2   feet     10.362694     992.380372
3   feet     14.020116      71.319720
4  meter    456.000000   45776.000000
```

You can take the opportunity to change the unit as well:

```
mask = df['unit'].eq('feet')
df.loc[mask, ['altitude_low','altitude_high']] /= 3.281
df.loc[mask, 'unit'] = 'meter'
```

Output:

```
    unit  altitude_low  altitude_high
0  meter    456.000000   25435.000000
1  meter    254.000000   35223.000000
2  meter     10.362694     992.380372
3  meter     14.020116      71.319720
4  meter    456.000000   45776.000000
```

##### alternative approach for multiple units:

Use a dictionary with the conversion factors

```
units = {'feet': 1/3.281, 'meter': 1}

cols = ['altitude_low','altitude_high']
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df['unit'].map(units), axis=0)
```

Comment: holy moly thanks a lot dude! you solve my problem!

Comment: @anjelitodevan if you have multiple units, you can use a dictionary, see update ;)